# dictionary performance based on key length

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, big-o

If I had a a dictionary with a huge key, would it make lookups significantly slower?

What I mean by huge key is :

`{"THIS IS A HUGE KEY THAT IS VERY LONG1" : 1, "THIS IS A HUGE KEY THAT IS VERY LONG2" : 2}`

Would a key that is a string of length 300 be significantly slower than a key of length 3? Since lookups for dictionaries are `O(1)`

Comment: I guess the implementation of dict will have to hash the string in its entirety so it could have a higher lookup cost than a shorter string. However as long as the length of the string is a constant lookup time will be O(1).

Comment: computing the `hash()` of a longer string will obviously take longer. Since strings are immutable, it's only necessary for an implementation to calculate it once and store the result

Comment: Related [Optimizing Python Dictionary Lookup Speeds by Shortening Key Size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496226/optimizing-python-dictionary-lookup-speeds-by-shortening-key-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to test this out empirically,

For cpython the answer is No, it doesn't take longer.
Other implementations may recalculate the hash on demand. You'll have to look into it yourself if you're not using cpython

If the keys are big and plentiful enough, you may notice effects due to cpu cache and swap though.